# Tweedie distribution without zeroes

Tags: r, glmm, glmmtmb, tweedie-distribution

Recently I've found the Tweedie distribution useful for modelling my plant shoot weight data in glmmTMB. I started using it because my shoot weight datasets have many zeroes, and it has yielded better fits than I was able to get with zero-inflated models.

One of my shoot weight datasets doesn't have zeroes, however (although it does have many <1 values). The Gaussian distribution fits this dataset well enough, but I don't think that the predictions it makes are correct. I tried this model with the Tweedie distribution, and I got a better fit and predictions that make more sense.

**Despite the good fit, is it invalid to use the Tweedie distribution when your data doesn't have zeroes?** This is the code I'm using:

```
Model4 <- glmmTMB(Shoot.weight ~ Species + N.Level + Rhizobia + Species:N.Level + 
                      Species:Rhizobia + N.Level:Rhizobia + N.Level:Rhizobia:Species + 
                     (1 | Block), family = tweedie, data = SOY)
```

I believe that the specific Tweedie distribution that I'm using here is the compound Poisson-Gamma distribution, but correct me if I'm wrong about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tweedie distributions don't always have zeros, but even when they do, often the proportion of zeros in fitted Tweedie models is often fairly small - at least in the cases I've seen it used to fit.  (Your post indicates you have $1<p<2$, so that would imply some zeroes in the model)

I think the Tweedie family is of relatively modest value for modelling data with zeroes: the proportion of zeroes you get in the model is not only affected by the proportion of zeroes in the data -- it's a function of $p$, $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ and a GLM will work with a fixed $p$, while the estimates of $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ will be affected by all the data.

However, the family can be quite handy if you want GLMs with variance functions that are a power of the mean.

You could attempt to identify the proportion of zeroes you're actually getting in your fitted model. I think that the proportion of zeroes is $\exp(-\frac{\mu^{2-p}}{(2-p)\sigma^2})$ (i.e. it varies with the fitted mean).

I wouldn't worry terribly much whether your data have zeros unless your fitted model suggests a fairly substantial proportion of them somewhere that you have a fair bit of data.